# Does there exist a compactly supported integrable function with infinite Coulomb energy?

Tags: measure-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, measure-concentration, physics, lebesgue-measure

The title of the question pretty much says it all.   I am looking for a function $f\in L^1(\Omega)$,  where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a bounded domain, such that 
$$
E[f] = \iint\limits_{\Omega\times\Omega} \frac{f(x)f(y)dxdy}{|x-y|}\text{ is infinite}.
$$  Suffice to take $f \geq 0$. Note that $f\notin L^\infty$ since the Coulomb potential is locally integrable.

Side note:  Apologies; being new here I accidentally asked this question first on the Mathematics Stack Exchange, not realizing that was a different site than mathoverflow.

Comment: What about letting $\epsilon > 0$ be small, and letting $\phi(x) = \chi(x) \cdot |x|^{\epsilon - 1}$ where $\chi(x)$ is a smooth cutoff that is equal 1 near the origin? Now if you set $f = \Delta \phi$ you have that $f$ is approximately $|x|^{\epsilon - 3}$ near the origin and is integrable, and so $f\cdot \phi \approx |x|^{2\epsilon - 4}$ is not integrable near the origin? (The standard Sobolev bound on the Coulumb energy is by $\|f\|_{L^{6/5}}$. So you really just need to find $f$ that is in $L^1$ but not in $L^{6/5}$ to get counter examples.)

Comment: Energy is related to integral norm of the squared derivatives. A function can be integrable but derivative very singular.

Comment: Very good, thank you @WillieWong!